# error in crystal report formula

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I dont understand  the error in formula in crystal report

```
Local StringVar DistStatePin;
DistStatePin := " ";
If Not isnull({DonationByReceiptNo.place}) Then DistStatePin := DistStatePin + Space(1) + Trim({DonationByReceiptNo.place}) + ", ";
If Not isnull({DonationByReceiptNo.district}) Then 
    If (Mid(Trim({DonationByReceiptNo.district}),2,Length(Trim({DonationByReceiptNo.district}))-2)) <> Trim({DonationByReceiptNo.place}) Then
    DistStatePin := DistStatePin + Space(1) + Trim({DonationByReceiptNo.district}) + ", ";
If Not isnull({DonationByReceiptNo.state}) Then 
    If Trim({DonationByReceiptNo.state}) <> Trim({DonationByReceiptNo.place}) Then
    DistStatePin := DistStatePin + Space(1) + Trim({DonationByReceiptNo.state});
If Not isnull({DonationByReceiptNo.Pincode}) Then DistStatePin := DistStatePin + Space(1) + Trim({DonationByReceiptNo.Pincode});

trim(DistStatePin);
```

and the error is

```
Error in File C:\Users\Gautam\AppData\Local\Temp\temp_d5c95ff2-0ec9-458e-8a3a-bc545097fd1a {9FBD7AEE-ED90-4886-848F-262758592B77}.rpt:
Error in formula  <DistState>. 
'Local StringVar DistStatePin;
'
String length is less than 0 or not an integer.
```

Comment: May be problem with this line `Length(Trim({DonationByReceiptNo.district}))`

Comment: Why are you declaring DistStatePin at the top without putting anything in it? Loose that second line as it is not needed and then also loose the "DistStatePin" when you actually put a value into the variable.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably this section:

```
Mid( Trim({DonationByReceiptNo.district}), 2, Length(Trim({DonationByReceiptNo.district}))-2 )
```

Refactored for clarity:

```
Local Stringvar district:=Trim({DonationByReceiptNo.district});
Mid( district, 2, Length(district)-2 );
```

If `district=""` Then your formula would be `Mid( "", 2, 0-2 )` which will give you an error.